# Wrong output while appending the elements of one ndarray to another ndarray in python

Tags: python, numpy, append, numpy-ndarray

I am working on my KNN project and have a dataset given, where there are 60,000 training_images and 60,000 training_labels , both are converted into ndarrays. Each element of the [training_image] represents a matrix(image), and each element of the [training_labels] presented in a form of one number in range of 1 to 10, i.e. [1.0 2.0 7.0 9.0 5.0 ... etc.]

I am writing a function that is devising a predicted response of most similar neighbors for a test instance. It assumes the class is the last attribute for each neighbor. For that I need to append to each of my training data([training_images] a value of [training_labels]. However when I was trying to do that, I ran into some issues:
         Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import operator
import csv
import random
import math
from scipy.io import loadmat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Loading the data
M = loadmat('x_data.mat')
images_train,images_test,labels_train,labels_test= M['images_train'],M['images_test'],M['labels_train'],M['labels_test']

#just to make all random sequences on all computers the same.
np.random.seed(1)

#randomly permute data points
inds = np.random.permutation(images_train.shape[0])
images_train = images_train[inds]
labels_train = labels_train[inds]

inds = np.random.permutation(images_test.shape[0])
images_test = images_test[inds]
labels_test = labels_test[inds]

for i in images_train:    
        for j in labels_train:
                i = np.append(i,labels_train[j])
```

So the thing is that I print my images_train again , it looks the same without any changes. On the other side if I do

```
b = labels_train[5]
b = np.append(b,(labels_train[5]))
print b
```

it gives me desirable output

So I don't know what is wrong with my loops or where the issue is. Or may be there is a better way to accomplish my goal by creating a dictionary, where each of the training labels will be keys to my training_data ?Can you please help of direct me towards the right solution.

Comment: Don't use np.append.  Hardly anyone uses it right.

Comment: Looks like you need some practice with simple list iterations.  Make sure you understand when the iteration is on indices versus actual elements.  And learn what you can do, and not do, with an iteration variable.

Comment: Expanding on my first comment.  `np.append` is not a good imitation of the list append.  It is slower, and trickier to use.  If you must iterate, build a list with list append, and turn that into an array with one call at the end.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, regarding your expanded answer, I don't really get what list I should build, is it like building a list and then appending elements from training data array and training labels array to this list?  Also, if I still want to use np.append could you tell me more precise, what is wrong with my loop and why it does not produce my output?

Comment: When `i` is the iteration variable, you can't assign new values to `i`.  Python loops don't work that way.  The `j` loop is also bad.  `j` is an element of `labels_train`.  You can't use it as an index to the same array.  As for `np.append`, it does not change the array inplace like the list append does.  It makes a new array, because it is just alternate way to call `np.concatenate`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, yeah that's right, my loops are totally screwed. I fixed it , but even if I use it, it works very slow, since there is a huge amount of data. Is there another method to map my labels to the array of data elements I was given?